# PSCustomObject - use contains filter on array

Tags: arrays, powershell, pscustomobject

i am trying to figure out how i can search a value in an array that is in a pscustomobject.

```
$global:RuleSet+= [pscustomobject][ordered]@{  RuName="NSMS" ;
                                               Agent=("ABC",  
                                                      "DFG",
                                                      "HIJ")}
$search = "ABC"

$myRuleSet = $RuleSet | Where-Object { $search -contains $_.Agent }
```

This was my attempt to solve the problem, but it dosn't seem to work that way. Can someone please explain to my how this could or should be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have the operands the wrong way around - `$_.Agent` resolves to the collection, so it should be the left-hand side of the `-contains` operation:

```
$global:RuleSet += [pscustomobject]@{
  RuName = "NSMS"
  Agent = @("ABC","DFG","HIJ")
}

$search = "ABC"

$myRuleSet = $RuleSet | Where-Object { $_.Agent -contains $search }
```

*Note: `[ordered]` is unnecessary when using `[pscustomobject]@{ ... }` instantiation syntax.*

Now that the property reference is on the left-hand side, we can rewrite the `Where-Object` statement to use its simpler property syntax:

```
$myRuleSet = $RuleSet | Where-Object Agent -contains $search
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. But after trying it out it still does not work. I've tried it with an eympt fresh script, no luck either. It does not seem to match for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: @pyte perhaps you forgot to create the `$RuleSet` array/list? `$global:RuleSet = @()`

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen No this would result in an error. I've created it in my script with `$global:RuleSet2 = @()` EDIT: Made a Typo in the Ruleset! Sorry :-) That fixed it!

Comment: @pyte `RuleSet` and `RuleSet2` are 2 different variable names, they won't resolve to the same thing

Comment: Made a Typo in the Ruleset! Sorry :-) That fixed it! RuleSet2 was from the testscript sorry for not clarifying it